# What options are there for ripping and storing DVD movies in a playable format?

Tags: windows-7, macos, backup, dvd

What options do I have for ripping and storing DVD movies in a playable format? I have several hundred DVDs and would like to back them up, but I also would like to be able to watch them.

I have both Mac and Windows machines (also have an OLD machine running Ubuntu but that is an older machine with < 40 GB). I would prefer to do this on Windows but OS X is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) runs on both Mac OS X and Windows and will convert the DVDs to H.264 for you. You'll need to have [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) installed in order to use deCSS that is part of VLC. You can find more about Handbrake through their [FAQ](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/SupportFAQ)

Answer (score 1):

Programme called 'Any DVD' from Slysoft removes CSS copyright keys etc and can you can use it to rip bought DVDs to your hard drive. To make an actual copy of a DVD, Clone DVD (from Elaborate Bytes)from same website does this (as does DVD shrink), but you need AnyDVD running in the background of both these programmesto remove the CSS keys etc.

Answer (score 0):

For OSX, [RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) from [the little app factory](http://thelittleappfactory.com/) will do the job, and is dead simple to use. The little app factory also offers a free application called [Evom](http://thelittleappfactory.com/evom/) which can convert your movies to ipod/itunes-friendly formats.